# How to duplicate a loop cut in blender

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to duplicate a loop cut on all the top teeth of the gear and I can't honestly remember how to do that. I haven't work in blender in a while and I completely forgot the basics. It must be a better way instead of doing it individually for every tooth. Picture attached bellow and ty for your time.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use *Inset Faces*. You can select loops where you want to add loop cuts by using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> and then press <kbd>I</kbd> to inset faces.

[image: Blender - Inset Faces]

Comment: Good solution. It doesn't work with alt + left click on my keyboard. Must be a setting in preferences I guess. I'm using Shift + left click to select the loops and I have to go individually for every tooth, but at least Inset procedure takes all at once. Ctrl + or Ctrl-Shit + doesn't work in this case for faster loop highlight.